# Powershell - unable to print value of hash

Tags: hash, parameters, powershell-2.0

I am writing a simple script to get more familiar with powershell.

This script reads input parameters into a hash

```
$states = @($args)

$states

write-host Color is $states.color
```

On the command-line, I set the following values

```
$shape = 'circle'; $color = 'pink'; $size = 'large'
```

I then invoke the program with the following command

```
.\shapes_n_colors.ps1  $shape $size $color
```

And, I get the following output:

```
circle
large
pink
Color is
```

I am unable to figure out why $states.color is blank. I was expecting the output "Color is pink"

I am following this artical, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847780.aspx

Where am I going wrong???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure where to start...

First of all - you don't create hash at any point... `@($args)` doesn't do anything: $args is already an array, and `@()` is only useful to make sure that expression will produce an array... Hash literal is `@{}`.

Next: your script will have no clue what names you've used for variables passed to it. It will see three strings. I would suggest using `param()` to get *named* parameters (that by default are also positional, so calling script wouldn't change much):

```
param (
    $Shape,
    $Size,
    $Color
)

Write-Host Color is $Color
```

When you try it with your syntax, it will produce expected results. But wait, there's more. ;) With this you could run your script without a need to remember param order:

```
.\shapes_n_colors.ps1 -Color White -Shape Circle -Size Small
```

Not to mention that  will complete this named parameters for you.